# Diagnosing an infrequent android cold reboot

Tags: android

I am programming an android application which causes my phone to reboot.

Similar questions have been asked before, but I am hoping to get some suggestions on how to diagnose the problem given specifics of my situation, which are as follows.

*Some context:*
The application uses a service running in the background, to periodically download JSON data from a server. Based on this data, it sets PendingIntent in alerts for the AlarmManager and proximity alerts for the LocationManager. The pendingIntents instantiate an activity with a webview component which renders an interface based on that JSON text.

Regarding reboots:*

- Reboots never happen when the phone is connected to the pc through the usb cable.
- Reboots are quite scarce. They take place maybe once a day, or sometimes even further apart. They also seem to be unpredictable. So even waiting for debug logs on `adb` over wifi
  does not seem to help.
- When feeling the phone right after a reboot, I have the impression that it is particularly hotter than usual on its back where the battery lies (but maybe it's just an impression)

Would be grateful for any suggestions towards diagnosing the problem.

Comment: How do you know that it is you causing the reboot?

Comment: The phone never reboots when my service or activities are not running